# Custom UITableViewCell using Storyboard

Tags: ios5, uitableview, storyboard

I'm trying to make a custom cell using storyboard.
I have tested my program with Basic cells and it worked.
Now I'have created a new class that I named NewsCell, which is containing the different Labels in the custom cell.
I have also made the cell a subclass of NewsCell. The cell identifier is "NewsCell".

This is the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NewsCell *cell = (NewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsCell"]; //signal : SIGABRT
    News *info = [self.news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titreLabel.text = info.titre;
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = info.description;
    return cell;
}
```

When I run my app, it crashes with a signal signal SIGABRT at the first ligne.
I'm sure that I've made the right connections between Labels and the table view cell.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The NIB data is invalid.'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turned out that I had checked "Use Autolayout" in the Interface Builder Document pane of the Storyboard file. This throws the "invalid NIB" error when running on iOS 5 because autolayout is only supported on iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created instance for the cell. Try to create instance for the cell.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    NewsCell *cell = (NewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsCell"]; //signal : SIGABRT

     if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[NewsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
    News *info = [self.news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titreLabel.text = info.titre;
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = info.description;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i'm trying to create a custom cell, not the basic one.

Comment: That `cell == nil`/create part is no longer necessary with Storyboards (and their template cells).