# App don't run on iOS 5, when target is iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I've made an App with the iOS 6.0 SDK. I've set the deployment target to iOS 5.0.

When I run the app in the iOS 6.0 simulator, everything is okay.
But when I will run the app in the iOS 5.0 simulator, I see an black window and Xcode said in the output:

```
2013-01-08 14:25:06.032 Feestweek[583:c07] Unknown class SASlideMenuStaticViewController in Interface Builder file.
2013-01-08 14:25:06.965 Feestweek[583:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The NIB data is invalid.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2159052 0x1f29d0a 0x2101a78 0x21019e9 0x14fd838 0x13a4e2c 0x13a53a9 0x150e5e2 0x13a55cb 0x1305a73 0x1305ce2 0x1305ea8 0x130cd9a 0x12ddbe6 0x12de8a6 0x12ed743 0x12ee1f8 0x12e1aa9 0x2043fa9 0x212d1c5 0x2092022 0x209090a 0x208fdb4 0x208fccb 0x12de2a7 0x12dfa9b 0x287d 0x27a5 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

What can I do to run my app also on iOS 5? I use Storyboard.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579844/custom-uitableviewcell-using-storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck the "use Autolayout" in the XIB. Xcode 4.5 enables this property by default for the new nib files you add into your project. Unchecking the autolayout check box solved the problem

Comment: even after a clean and recompile?

Comment: you need to turn it off in the storyboard under document. then on every xib and every control under "Interface Builder Document"

Comment: product clean, then product run/build

Comment: Under deployment under Document Versioning you can also selet Deployments, they also have "All Versions of iOS"

Comment: Did you check every view, every uiview, uilabel, uiimage, control, every single control with every single xib, and ensure that Autolayout is off.

Comment: In your storyboard, also view controller, view, first responder, and exit all need use Autolayout turned off. It's probably in 10 different places.

Comment: I've check everything, all checked off.

Comment: did you ever get this Rick?